# How can I align a flexbox to the bottom of its parent tag?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align the whole flexbox which has other little "flexboxes" inside it to the end of the home section but somehow if I write position: absolute; and bottom: 0; to .countdowns it doesn't follow the space-between command.

```css
#home {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .countdowns {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .coming-soon {
      min-height: 10vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .countdown {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .countdown h4 {
      margin: 0;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .day, .hour, .minute, .second {
      font-size: 1rem;
      padding: 25px;
      flex-basis: 0;
    }
    
    }
```

```html
<section id="home">
        <hr>
        <div class="box">
          <h1><div></div></h1>
        </div>
        <h2>blablabla</h2>
        <a href="#about">
          <img src="img/arrow.png" alt="arrow">
        </a>
        <div class="countdowns">
        <div class="coming-soon2">
          <h3>blabla</h3>
            <div class="countdown2">
              <div class="container-day2">
                <h4 class="day2">Time</h4>
                <h4>DAYS</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="container-hour2">
                <h4 class="hour2">Time</h4>
                <h4>HOURS</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="container-minute2">
                <h4 class="minute2">Time</h4>
                <h4>MINS</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="container-second2">
                <h4 class="second2">Time</h4>
                <h4>SECS</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: show us your html

Comment: @pinar can you please provide a markup image that shows your desired result?

Comment: guess your problem is to forget to close one of the divs try checking your div numbers as i checked you have open 9 but only close 8 of them and it seems the one with .countdowns is the one which is not closed so if you copied your code here check it in your own source it may solve your problem.